# Detect IE10 on XBOX

Tags: javascript, css, html5-video, xbox360, internet-explorer-10

How do I detect IE10 on XBOX 360?

Everything formats well--UNICORN passed completely--but HTML5 video does not display properly on IE for XBOX 360 with the styling I used (and no, the styling must remain the same). All other desktop browsers (IE9, IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari & Opera) handle it perfectly. I've already disabled the video tag when mobile devices such as iPad, Android and IE10 Metro are detected since they have the same issue, but I haven't found much written on the topic of IE for XBOX catches. Certainly, IE for XBOX isn't a priority, but it's the last browser that I need to counter program for. Thanks for your time and knowledge!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but how about looking for "MSIE 10.0" and "Xbox" in the user agent string? http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/category/32/index.html / http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/category/36/index.html

Comment: This will not work, as IE for Xbox is IE9 not IE10, and the UA string reflects that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no IE10 on XBox. It is based on IE9, so in theory if your site works in IE9 desktop it should work fairly well on the XBox, except for adaptations that need to be made to display well on a screen you interact with from distance with alternative input methods.

You can find the IE for XBox developer’s guide at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30442

You should only detect the User Agent string as a last resort. The UA strings for IE for XBox are:

- Desktop mode: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; Xbox)
- Mobile mode: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; Xbox)

The regular UA string is desktop mode. A user can switch to mobile mode if they have a SD TV and the web page would work better if given the mobile version. The key token to detect is "Xbox".